# How do I fork a new process with independent stdout, stderr, and stdin?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, fork

I have read most of the related questions about subprocess and os.fork(), including all the discussions about the double forking trick. However, none of the those solutions appear to work correctly for my scenario.

I want to fork a new process and allow the parent to terminate (normally) without screwing up the child's stdin, stdout, and stderr and without killing the child.

My first attempt was to use `subprocess.Popen()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import call,Popen

Popen("/bin/bash", shell=True)
call("echo Hello > /tmp/FooBar", shell=True)
```

This fails because the child process is killed once the parent is exits. I am aware of `creationflags` but that is Windows-specific and I am running on Linux. Note that the above code works beautifully if we simply keep the parent process alive by adding an infinite loop to the end of it. This is undesirable because the parent is already finished with its job and there's no real reason for it to stick around.

---

The second attempt was to use `os.fork()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import call
from os import fork


try: 
  pid = fork()
  if pid > 0: 
    pass    
  else: # child process will start interactive process
    call("/bin/bash", shell=True)
except:
  print "Forking failed!"

call("echo Hello > /tmp/FooBar", shell=True)
```

Here, the child process no longer dies with the parent, but after the parent's death the child can no longer read input and write output.

Thus, I want to know how I fork a new process with utterly independent `stdout`, `stderr`, and `stdin`. Independence means that the parent process can terminate (normally), and the child process (whether it is bash or tmux or any other interactive program) behaves *exactly as though the parent program had not terminated*. To be even more precise, consider the following variation of the original program.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import call,Popen

Popen("/bin/bash", shell=True)
call("echo Hello > /tmp/FooBar", shell=True)
while True:
   pass
```

The above code has all the behaviors I seek, but it keeps the Python process alive artificially. I am trying to achieve this exact behavior, *without the Python process being alive*.

**Caveat**: I am running these applications over ssh, so spawning a new GUI window is not a viable solution.

**Desired Behavior**:

1. I run the python code.
2. I get a shiny new `bash` shell that works exactly like the bash shell I started with.
3. The file `/tmp/FooBar` is created.
4. The original Python script finishes.
5. I continue on with my shiny new bash shell, and the output of `ps aux | grep python` does not include python script I just ran.

Comment: (In that Popen technique) Is child a daemon? If not then how come it  terminates as soon as the parent dies?

Comment: Can't >>> Popen("tmux  -S /tmp/TestSmux attach-session", shell=True) be done in a separate thread? This thread mustn't be a daemon otherwise it won't give the desired result. You can keep the RUN method for this thread from completing until your task is done... this way your parent process would continue doing its work and you could actually signal from the child (an event) if you wish to run some code in the parent based on the input received in the child.
Then you could signal from the parent (to stop the child) or join making sure parent and child both stop.

Comment: 1. `tmux` is a complicated example. If you *need* `tmux`; ask about a specific issue that you have with it.  2. Is your quesiton: how to emulated `nohup`, `disown` or create a proper daemon in Python?

Comment: @SyedMauzeRehan, I've given you the complete reproducible example, and my observations of the behavior. It behaves like a daemon, but is it one? I can't say I know for sure.

Comment: @SyedMauzeRehan, For the suggestion of the separate thread, that's what I will try if I can't make this work with processes alone. However, if you think it will work and you have the time to test it and make sure that all the user-interaction works correctly, you are welcome to write an answer.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, Please take the question exactly as it is written. If I replaced `tmux attach-session` with `vim` and replaced the command after `vim` with  something else that then exited, it would be the same problem. With respect to your clarifying question, I am trying to emulate none of those or all of those, depending on whether or not they achieve the behavior I have described -- maintain an interactive session, run more code, and then exit in the parent process without making life difficult for the child.

Comment: @merlin2011:  `Popen()` doesn't wait for the command to finish. How do you know that it doesn't return in your example? Are absolutely sure that you need all these commands to reproduce your issue? For example, even `python -c 'import subprocess; subprocess.Popen("/bin/bash")'` has I/O issues on my system.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, If the concern is that my example is more complicated than it needs to be because of `tmux`, that is a completely fair criticism. I will edit the question when I get back to my computer. I originally used this particular MWE because it happened to be the problem I was trying to solve, not because I didn't think the problem was general.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, Please see the edited question, which has removed all references to `tmux`.

Comment: *"This fails because the child process is killed once the parent is killed"* -- why do you kill it instead of allowing it exit normally? Why do you need `shell=True`?

Comment: @j.f.sebastian I don't kill it just let it terminate. I don't need shell true for the example but I think that is an orthogonal issue?

Comment: `p = Popen(['x-terminal-emulator', '-e', '/bin/bash'])` opens the shell in a new terminal. Depending on the terminal you may be able to wait for the terminal window to close via `p.wait()`. You can't with gnome-terminal unless you run it directly with the option `--disable-factory`. But it looks like you don't want the parent to wait anyway, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: How do you run the parent? Child processes are not killed on the parent exit

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I run it using `./MWE.py`. I also try running it using `python MWE.py`. Also, please see the change in the title of the question. I have tried to generalize it a little more for clarity and breadth.

Comment: @merlin2011: 1. the child process is *not* killed when the parent exits (as I've already said) e.g., run: `python -c 'import subprocess; subprocess.Popen("sleep 3; echo alive", shell=True)'` -- if you run it; you first willl see the prompt (when the parent exits) and then `"alive"` is printed. In your case the child is probably killed by SIGHUP signal when your ssh connection is interrupted or you logout -- run the Python script inside screen to avoid it.

Comment: 2. "independent stdin, etc" -- independent from what? the terminal where you type? (parent's standard streams are connected to it) -- try to describe the desired behavior from a user point of view: how do you want it to look like? e.g., login via ssh, attach screen session (or create a new one), run the script, parent exits, type some commands to the child interactively, logout, login again, attach the session, proceed.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, To your first comment, the code you give does not run unless `shell=True` is passed, but when that is passed it does work. However, if you replace the command with `bash`, the observed behavior is that after the parent terminates, hitting any key will cause GUI terminal to close, and the virtual terminal to log out. Note that I am testing on `localhost` to avoid any kind of ssh issues. When running inside screen, pushing any key causes `screen` to terminate instead of the GUI terminal.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I have also added a very specific definition of independent, as well as the code that produces the behavior I desire by persisting the life of the parent process artificially.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example has an extra unnecessary call to Popen(), as the [call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) convenience function will just execute its commands in a shell and exit, so it would work if you just ran:

```
from subprocess import call, Popen

call("echo Hello > /tmp/FooBar", shell=True)
```

However if you want to send a series of commands to a shell then the shell needs to opened with stdin attached to pipe so it doesn't get mixed up with the parents stdin (which is effectively what you're asking for in terms of obtaining independent stdio):

```
p = Popen("/bin/bash", shell=True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write("echo Hello > /tmp/FooBar\n")
p.stdin.write("date >> /tmp/FooBar\n")
p.terminate()
```

If you want to also control the output then you redirect stdout and stderr to PIPE (i.e. `stdout = subprocess.PIPE`, `stderr = subprocess.PIPE`) and then call p.stdout.read() to obtain output as needed.

To allow the process to continue running after exiting python one can add `&` operator to the end of the command so it continues running in the background e.g.:

```
call("nc -l 2000 > /tmp/nc < &",shell=True)
```

To have a process run so that both stdin and stdout and still connected one can use shell redirects. To maintain access to stdin one can create a named pipe using `mkfifo`  e.g:

```
call("mkfifo /tmp/pipe",shell=True)
call("tail -f /tmp/pipe > /tmp/out &",shell=True)
```

To provide input stdin one just send data to the pipe .e.g. from the shell:

```
$ echo 'test' > /tmp/pipe
```

Comment: This answer does not achieve the behavior I describe in the question. Please read the last part of the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer - if you background the process then it continues after python exits.

Comment: This does not address the issue of maintaining interactive `stdin` for the subprocess.

Comment: I've added another update to explain how one can use a pipe to maintain access to stdin.

Comment: These are useful hacks,  but they miss the main problem: maintaining an interactive shell that behaves exactly like any other shell.

Comment: The subprocess shell command can be interacted with using the PIPEs connected to stdin/out (and doesn't get killed after python exits) but I guess if u want fully interactive access to shell you're looking using screen/tmux or duplicating that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem, I found a solution that might help,
using `creationflags` to tell Popen that the child process should not inherit the parent process console, and thus has it's own stdout, stdin and stderr as if it was a parent process.

```
subprocess.Popen("/bin/bash", creationflags= subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Popen supports `creationflags` keyword argument according to docs:

> creationflags, if given, can be one or more of the following flags:
>
> CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
>
> CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
>
> ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
>
> BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
>
> HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS
>
> IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS
>
> NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
>
> REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS
>
> CREATE_NO_WINDOW
>
> DETACHED_PROCESS
>
> CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE
>
> CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB

The ones that you are interested in are `DETACHED_PROCESS` and `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, I've used `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, what it does is it spawns a new process as if it was a parent, I used Python3.5 Windows, in Python 3.7 `DETACHED_PROCESS` was added and it's documented to do the same as `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`.